# SSMS Timout problems

Tags: sql-server-2008, timeout, ssms-2017

I have weird behaviour in SSMS 2017.
I am trying to run some stored procedure in SSMS and I get next message every time trying to run it:

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

First, by default timeout was set to 1 second, then I tried with 10 seconds and last I have tried with 0 seconds. Even tho it says 0 seconds is avoiding timeout, it still have timeout.

The most weird thing is that when I run this stored procedure within the application, everything is working fine. I am confused and I don't know what to do.

I am working with SSMS 2017 with DB from SQL Server 2008.

Comment: is it connecting to a linked server or some other external database?

Comment: Nope. It is local server with local database. Could that be a bug that it have timeout whether or not I set 0 for timeout in options?

Comment: I'd pull the commands out of the SP and run them as ad hoc queries, or run Profiler with statement level tracing, or use the debug stored procedure to see what it's doing when it fails. Does it return the error immediately or after a period of time?